# Why does Google structure their spreadsheet JSON objects the way they do?

Tags: json, google-sheets-api, gdata

I'm using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) to retrieve a spreadsheet and parse through it. I'm using javascript and I'm requesting JSON (the documentation for the REST API is actually in the old [Google Data API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/developers-guide) docs - very annoying!).

Here is the URL I am using to `GET` the data, where `ID` is the ID of the spreadsheet:

`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/"+ID+"/1/public/values?alt=json`

This will get each cell for the first worksheet, however, all cells are listed in a single array.

```
feed: {
    entry: [
        0: {
            gs$cell: {
                row: 1,
                col: 1,
                $t: 'Value'
            }
        },
        1: {
            gs$cell: {
                row: 2,
                col: 1,
                $t: 'Other Value'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This means I have to iterate through the array (`data.feed.entry`) using a for loop, check which row it is in using `data.feed.entry[i].gs$cell.row`, and then sort each cell into arrays for each row. This seems like a lot of extra work just to format the JSON object for consumption.

I'm just wondering why Google would have structured their JSON object like this. Why wouldn't they group the cells by row, to begin with? I feel like I'm missing something.

Then I thought maybe it'd be better to GET the entire row using `list` rather than  `cells`, but when I do, the columns are defined by their values, meaning the content can't be dynamic. You'd have to know the header values before parsing the data...

```
feed: {
    entry: [
        0: {
            gsx$MyColumnValue: {
                row: 1,
                col: 1,
                $t: 'Value'
            }
        },
        1: {
            gsx$MyOtherColumnValue: {
                row: 2,
                col: 1,
                $t: 'Other Value'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Again, I am at a loss as to why Google would structure their JSON this way. Do you know why? What am I missing?

Comment: @player0 I don't think that google-apps-script applies to this question as it's about [tag:google-sheets-api] and it doesn't mention any google-apps-scripts feature.

Comment: This is an old question that seems to only have opinion based answers as possibilities, and probably also requires internal Google knowledge. Seems appropriate to close, especially since sheets API us properly released and documented, and this question is about v3..

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (and for posterity), you can change `cells` to `list` to get a row-by-row based response.

E.g. `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEET-ID/1/public/values?alt=json`